# How to format a string as a date

Tags: php, date, formatting

Ok so im trying to display a date that i got from a database

Here's what i can display without any formatting: `2012-11-21 19:00:00`

what im trying to display is: `2012-11-21 at 19:00:00`

below is the code

```
$expiryDate = date('Y/m/d', $data[0]->dinExpiry);
$expiryTime = date('H:i', $data[0]->dinExpiry);
```

And this is the error im getting;

[image]

Also the date that it displays is wrong

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What is the raw value in `$data[0]->dinExpiry`? I'm guessing it's NOT a valid PHP timestamp value, given you're getting 1970 out of it, which means it's being translated to 0.

Comment: `var_dump($data[0]->dinExpiry))` .... what is the content

Comment: So.. what you're trying to display is basically the same as what it already outputs?  It doesn't match your string at all.

Comment: please write here what you get when you do print_r($data)

Comment: var_dump: string(19) "2012-11-21 19:00:00"

Comment: print_r: 2012-11-21 19:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easy solution

You say that you can display `2012-11-21 19:00:00` without any formatting.

So if you can display an arbitrary $date as 2012-11-21 19:00:00, why not just substring it:

```
$dateToDisplay = substr($date, 0, 11).'at '.substr($date, 11, 8);
```

and show $dateToDisplay as `2012-11-21 at 19:00:00`.

### A little more...

It's tricky to answer this without knowing the output of $data[0]->dinExpiry. (I'll assume it gives you a variable called $date).

As @Marc B says, the fact that you're getting 1970 out of it shows that it's not a valid timestamp *(hint: it's a string)*, so it's evaluated to zero seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

You can convert it to a valid timestamp like so:

```
$expiryDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Or to match your example:

```
$expiryDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[0]->dinExpiry));
$expiryTime = date('H:i', strtotime($data[0]->dinExpiry));
```

Comment: You are awesome!! It turned out to be the strtotime. As soon as I used that it worked ill post the code when I get home in case anyone wants to see it. Thank you soooooooooo much